# Why is Axios posting the wrong data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm confused with Axios:

In my Vue template I have a list of JS objects, each element is like:

```
covs.all_batches_tuples[
...
{'id': 45, 'bname': 'tcp_S1153', 'selected': False}
...
]
```

I have a checkbox loop:

```
<v-row>
   <v-col v-for="batch in covs.all_batches_tuples" :key="batch.id" class="pa-0 ma-0 text-body-2" cols="1">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="batch.id" v-model="batch.selected" :value="batch.bname"
  @click="selected_batches()"/>
      <label :for="batch.id">{{ batch.bname }}</label>
   </v-col>
</v-row>
```

and finally I have a method that is fired after clicking a checkbox:

```
methods: {
    selected_batches() {
      console.log("1 ", this.covs.all_batches_tuples)
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://192.168.21.152:8002/showAnns/covs/',
        data: {
          checked_batches_ids_string: this.covs.all_batches_tuples,
        },
      })
      console.log("2 ", this.covs.all_batches_tuples)
    },
}
```

In Chrome the initial state looks like this:

[image]

when I click a checkbox, the `selected_batches` method fires two console.log() functions, and axios funciton.

All variables (`this.covs.all_batches_tuples`) are the same variables and in `console.log` looks good, the checkbox is selected:

[image]

But in axios post it as unselected:

[image]

If I click this checkbox again, so it is "unchecked", the axios shows it as "checked":
[image]

What is going on here? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

This problem actually happens because the `v-model` update later after the `axios` is called. In this case, you can use `@change` instead of `@input`.

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col v-for="batch in covs.all_batches_tuples" :key="batch.id" class="pa-0 ma-0 text-body-2" cols="1">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="batch.id" v-model="batch.selected" :value="batch.bname" @change="selected_batches" />
    <label :for="batch.id">{{ batch.bname }}</label>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```